# how to return the index of an element in an array using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, indexof

I have and array (`$rootScope.searchItemst`) of 194 items in JavaScript.
my `searchText` is a value user needs o know if exists in `searchItemst` array

I am using `indexof` but it always returns me `-1` even if it exists

```
a = $rootScope.searchItemst.indexOf($scope.searchText);
```

how can I get the indexof an element using angularjs?

this is my `$rootScope.searchItems` result in console:

```
Array[194][0 … 99]0: "test-00074"1: "test-00100"2: "test-00111"3: "test-00200"4: "test-00208"5: "test-00230"6: "test-00253"7: "test-00256"8: "test-00260"9: "test-00261"10: "test-00319"11: "test-00331"12: "test-00371"13: "test-00378"14: "test-00418"15: "test-00429"16: "test-00438"17: "test-00448"18: "test-00784"19: "test-00841"20: "test-00865"21: "test-00949"22: "test-01005"23: "test-01079"24: "test-01122"25: "test-01148"26: "test-01239"27: "test-01257"28: "test-01266"29: "test-01283"30: "test-01405"31: "test-01421"32: "test-01535"33: "wfp-01767"34: "test-02396"35: "test-02785"36: "test-02949"37: "test-03618"38: "test-03979"39: "test-04215"40: "test-04488"41: "wfp-04750"42: "test-04994"43: "test-05032"44: "test-05085"45: "test-05126"46: "test-05131"47: "test-06010"48: "test-06269"49: "test-06306"50: "test-06315"51: "test-06479"52: "test-06781"53: "test-07156"54: "test-07237"55: "test-07302"56: "test-07333"57: "test-07431"58: "test-07526"59: "test-07582"60: "test-07604"61: "test-07642"62: "test-07765"63: "test-07802"64: "test-07864"65: "test-08053"66: "test-08283"67: "test-08292"68: "test-08294"69: "test-08295"70: "test-08297"71: "test-08298"72: "test-08299"73: "test-08308"74: "test-08309 "75: "test-08310"76: "test-08311"77: "test-08312"78: "test-08313"79: "test-08320"80: "test-08321"81: "test-08322"82: "test-08324"83: "test-08325"84: "test-08332"85: "test-08334"86: "test-08336"87: "test-08338"88: "test-08339"89: "test-08340"90: "test-08341"91: "test-08349"92: "test-08350"93: "test-08351"94: "test-08352"95: "test-08353"96: "test-08356"97: "test-08365 "98: "test-08416"99: "test-08417"[100 … 193]length: 194__proto__: Array[0]
```

Comment: Are you sure `$scope.searchText` has the correct value?

Comment: show us the array with values.

Comment: yes it has the value

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

let us consider you use list to display the array

```
<ul ng-repeat="x in searchItemst">
   <li ng-click="indexArray($index)">{{x}}</li>
</ul>
```

inside your controller

```
$scope.indexArray = function($index){

console.log($index);

}
```

the above console.log will print you the respected index number.